# What is standard number of workers and threads to use for uWSGI server?

Tags: http, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have a Nginx web server with uWSGI app server installed on a single CPU Ubuntu 14.04 image.

This uWSGI app server successfully handles a Flask app requests. 
The problem I am facing is that sometimes requests from a single client will time out for an extended period of time (1-2 hours).

This was happening without specifying workers or threads in my uwsgi.conf file. 
Is there an ideal amount of workers/threads to be used per CPU?

I am using emperor service to start the uWSGI app server. 
This is what my uwsgi.conf looks like

```
description "uWSGI"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
respawn

env UWSGI=/var/www/parachute_server/venv/bin/uwsgi
env LOGTO=/var/log/uwsgi/emperor.log

exec $UWSGI --master --workers 2 --threads 2 --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --die-on-term --uid www-data --gid www-data --logto $LOGTO --stats 127.0.0.1:9191
```

Could this be a performance problem in regards to nginx / uwsgi or is it more probable that these timeouts are occuring because I am only using a single CPU?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

Interesting issue you have...

Generally, you'd specify at least 2 * #CPUs + 1. This is because uWSGI might be performing a read/write to a socket, and then you'll have another worker accepting requests. Also, the `threads` flag is useful if your workers are synchronous, because they can notify the master thread that they are still busy working and so preventing a timeout.

I think having one worker was the reason for your timeout (blocking all other requests), but you should inspect your responses from your app. If they are taking a long time (say reading from db), you'll want to adjust the `uwsgi_read_timeout` directive in Nginx to allow uWSGI to process the request.

I hope this helps.